# How to split characters and calculate the corresponding frequency in R

Tags: r, split, character, frequency-analysis

Here is my data:

```
 [1] NA                                              NA                                             
 [3] NA                                              "EP, IP, RA, SH"
 [5] "EO, EP"                                        NA
```

I split the data using:

```
da$name<-str_split(da$name,",")
```

and the data become:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] "EP"  " IP" " RA"  " SH"

[[5]]
[1] "EO" " EP"         

[[6]]
[1] NA
```

and I want to calculate the frequency of NA,"EP","IP","RA","SH" and "EO"

Is there a possible way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best or more elegant way of doing it, but a possible solution is to `unlist` your `strsplit` result in order to make it a vector of all individual values and then to count for each different values:

```r
df <- data.frame(Vec = c(NA,NA,NA,"EP, IP, RA, SH","EO, EP",NA))

vec <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$Vec),","))

library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(vec) %>% count(vec)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  vec       n
  <fct> <int>
1 " EP"     1
2 " IP"     1
3 " RA"     1
4 " SH"     1
5 "EO"      1
6 "EP"      1
7  NA       4
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: what if I have a column representing "year", for example, and I want to calculate the frequency of different vec under different year. `df <- data.frame(Vec = c(NA,NA,NA,"EP, IP, RA, SH","EO,EP",NA),year=c(2015,2016,2017,2017,2016,2016))`, but when I split it and make it a vector, the row number of (Vec) is not the same as "year"

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could `unlist` the column, remove `NA` values, split them on comma and calculate the frequency using `table`.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(na.omit(unlist(as.character(da$name))), ",")))
```